# KendoUI Grid - filter not showing

Tags: angularjs, angular-kendo

In my angular-kendo application I'm unable to get the Grid filter to show at all - not even a filter icon, just plain column headers.
Here is my html:

```
<div ng-controller="IntroductionWizardCtrl">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Step 2: Select Application To Describe</h3>

    <div kendo-grid id="grid"
            k-data-source="dataSource"
            k-sortable="true"
            k-on-change="selectedItem = data"
            k-selectable="'row'"
            k-pageable='{ "refresh": true, "pageSizes": 5 }'
            k-filterable="true">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>{{selectedItem}}</p>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" wz-next value="Proceed to Next Step"
           data-ng-click="" />
</div>
```

here is the corresponding Angular controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('wizardApp').controller('IntroductionWizardCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope',
    function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {

        $scope.dataSource = {
            data: [{id: 1, name: "Account Underwriting - Misc App", bu: 50},
                {id: 2, name: "Achieve - Distributed", bu: 43},
                {id: 3, name: "ACT!", bu: 27},
                {id: 4, name: "Actuarial Database", bu: 29},
                {id: 5, name: "Adjustment Invoicing System (AIS)", bu: 34},
                {id: 6, name: "buncy Download", bu: 43},
                {id: 7, name: "Ariba", bu: 27},
                {id: 8, name: "Athena NY", bu: 29},
                {id: 9, name: "Authoria", bu: 34},
                {id: 10, name: "Avenue", bu: 43},
                {id: 11, name: "BC&IT - Services", bu: 27},
                {id: 12, name: "Billing Website", bu: 29},
                {id: 13, name: "Blue Butler", bu: 34},
                {id: 14, name: "BOE External", bu: 43},
                {id: 15, name: "Builders Risk", bu: 27},
                {id: 16, name: "Business Intelligence", bu: 29},
                {id: 17, name: "Care Center", bu: 34}],

                pageSize: 5, serverFiltering: true

        };
        $scope.rowSelected = function(e) {
            var grid = e.sender;
            var selectedRows = grid.select();
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                $scope.selectedItem = grid.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
                break;
            }
        };


        $scope.categoryDataSelectedRows=[];

        $scope.categoryData=
            {
        data:
            [{name: "General Application Information"},
            {name: "User Interface configuration description"},
            {name: "Application Architecture"},
            {name: "Database"},
            { name: "Backup & DR"},
            {name: "Design"},
            { name: "Operational data"},
            { name: "Testing"},
            {name: "Application Configuration details"},
            { name: "Application connectivity requirements"},
            {name: "Deployment Requirements"},
            {name: "Application dependencies"},
            {name: "Infrastructure dependencies"},
            { name: "Business value assessment"},
            { name: "Data requirements"},
            {name: "Hosting OS requirements"},
            { name: "License requirements"}], pageSize: 5
    }

        $scope.rowSelectedCategory = function(e) {
            var gridCategory = e.sender;
            var selectedRowsCategory = gridCategory.select();
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedRowsCategory.length; i++) {
                $scope.selectedItemCategory = gridCategory.dataItem(selectedRowsCategory[i]);
                break;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

I have looked over many examples, outside of Angular, where Kendo Grid has filtering working just fine. Yet, with angular-kendo I'm having this problem.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775520/angular-kendo-grid-filternot-showing)?  Anyway, can you provide a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Never created a fiddle before. Here is my first one for this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/JLMWa/11/

Comment: Just made an update - removed a few things to make it more readable:  http://jsfiddle.net/JLMWa/14/

Comment: There are a bunch of problems with that jsfiddle that appear in the browser console.  Can you fix those?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, my issue was with the order in which various css files were being loaded.
bootstrap was overwriting some other styles. Took me a while to sort this out, but now my angular-kendo grid is OK. Thanks for helping me!